# EJB with JNDI not listed in the glassfish JNDI list

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3, jndi

I have made an EJB with JNDI, using the annotations.
I made a jar of that EJB code and deployed it in the GlassFish server (version 3).
I am able to get the object of the EJB in a remote client application, using the JNDI lookup.
But I am not able to get the EJB name or the `mappedName` in the GlassFish JNDI list.
I use the command `asadmin list-jndi-entries` to get the list of JNDI entries.

```
@Remote
public interface TestEjbJndi {
    public Object test();
}
```

---

```
@Stateless(name="TestSdkInterface", mappedName="/test/ejb/jndi")
public class TestEjbJndiImpl implements TestEjbJndi{    
    @Override
    public Object test(){
        System.out.println("Inside getProtocolData");
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RemoteClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
            lookup(ctx);
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void lookup(Context ctx) throws NamingException {
        System.out.println("Inside lookup");
        try{
            Object object = ctx.lookup("/test/ejb/jndi");
            System.out.println("lookup done, object :"+object);

            TestEjbJndiImpl teji= (TestEjbJndiImpl)object;
            teji.test();
        }catch(NamingException ne){
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output of "asadmin list-jndi-entries"? Cause I think the JNDI name is made of the mapped name + the remote interface name.

Comment: Hi Amir,  The output of "asadmin list-jndi-entries":  
ehimkak@GWH7WS1:~/Downloads/GlassFish/glassfish3/bin$ ./asadmin list-jndi-entries  
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext  
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext  
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext  
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager:  com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl  
: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext  
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.

Comment: That's strange. The root context should've been shown. What's the output of "asadmin list-jndi-entries --context java:global/your-app-name". Replace "your-app-name" with the name of your application in GlassFish.

Comment: ehimkak@GWH7WS1:~/Downloads/GlassFish/glassfish3/bin$ ./asadmin list-jndi-entries --context java:global/testSdk      
TestSdkInterface: javax.naming.Reference
TestSdkInterface__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__: javax.naming.Reference
TestSdkInterface!test.erdm.classes.ProtocolDataPlugin: javax.naming.Reference
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
ehimkak@GWH7WS1:~/Downloads/GlassFish/glassfish3/bin$